# How do you adjust PopupWindow Width in Android

Tags: android, listview, popup

I want to sow a popup at specific location on a textview (textview is inside a scrollview). My PopupWindow layout only contains a listview. I am using below code to adjust the PopupWindow width and and height. PopupWindow height works correct but width not. It appear different on different devices. It also not warping the width of listview contents.

```
final PopupWindow attachmentPopup = new PopupWindow(this);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);
ListView lv = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
final ArrayList<CustomItem> popupItems = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
final CustomAdapter popupAdapter = new CustomAdapter(popupItems, Details.this);
CustomItem item;
item = new CustomItem();
item.setName("Apple");
popupItems.add(item);
item = new CustomItem();
item.setName("Orange");        
popupItems.add(item);
lv.setAdapter(popupAdapter);
int popupWidth =  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int popupHeight = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
attachmentPopup.setFocusable(true);
attachmentPopup.setWidth(popupWidth);
attachmentPopup.setHeight(popupHeight);
attachmentPopup.setContentView(popupView);
attachmentPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
attachmentPopup.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, mx, my);
```

popupwindow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#9acd32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try replacing this

```
int popupWidth =  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int popupHeight = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

with

```
int popupWidth = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int popupHeight = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Comment: The results are same. I think, because of listview it is not measuring width of listview items correctly.

Comment: @user934820 I am not sure but can you please try setting android:orientation="vertical" inside your linear layout of popup-view

Comment: would you mind sharing whole code so that I can compile at my end ?

Comment: it is already vertical. The whole code is too big. You can use any custom listview adapter to check it as the problem is with the listview contents (I have checked it by hiding listview and  putting a button instead).

Comment: @user934820 can you try using list pop-window instead of pop-window although which uses the width of anchor view but will solve your problem.

Comment: I have added android:layout_width="160dp" in both listview and layout which solved the problem (although it is not a proper solution).

Comment: I downvoted because this makes no sense since `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` are both integers of the same value **-2**